# How to get the infinispan cache statistics without using JMX?

Tags: caching, statistics, jmx, infinispan

I trying to get the cache statistics programmatically in infinispan without JMX.

I used Ehcache in the past, it has a nice way to get the statistics programmatically like cache.getHitCount().

Any ideas on how to do the same in infinispan?

Note: I'm using Infinispan 6.0.2 version which comes by default with Wildfly 8.2.0.Final.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the stats via [a AdvancedCache.getStats()](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/AdvancedCache.html#getStats--).

For example, from a `Cache` instance:

```
cache.getAdvancedCache().getStats().getHits()
```